# Pass Hash as Parameter to Rake Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, rake

I've got a rake task

```
task :post_hit, [:host, :title, :description, :model, :num_assignments, :reward, :lifetime, :qualifications, :p, :opts] => :environment do |t, args|
```

`:p` needs to be a hash, but if I try:

```
rake turkee:post_hit["http://www.staging.collegesportsbluebook.com","LS Info","Fill In Player First Name","MechanicalTurk",100,0.01,2,{},{id: 5},{}]
```

It errors out saying that `id:` could not be parsed (the space seemed to do something).

If I tried:

```
rake turkee:post_hit["http://www.staging.collegesportsbluebook.com","LS Info","Fill In Player First Name","MechanicalTurk",100,0.01,2,{},{"id: 5"},{}]
```

the who string `"id: 5"` was being interpreted as a single string.

Are we not allowed to pass hashes to rake tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you issue a rake task via the terminal, you are in the UNIX or Bash environment, so you need to obey the rules of that language, which as far as I can tell doesn't include hashes. I could be wrong though.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html#toc5

This doesn't mean that whoever wrote the rake task didn't do something clever to parse a string into a hash. If I were you and trying to figure it out I would have a look at the source code and see how that rake task parses it's variables.

PS. If it's a gem you are using and you are using bundler as well, you can issue `bundle open gem_name` to open up the source, rake tasks generally end in a .rake...

Answer (score 17):

I use querystring-like parameters and parse them with `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query`

Here's how I do it

```
require 'rack/utils' # needed for Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query

namespace :foo do
  task :bar, [ :args_expr ] => :environment do |t, args|
     args.with_defaults(:args_expr => "name=abdo&fruits[]=bananas&fruits[]=dates")
     options = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(args[:args_expr])

     puts options
  end
end
```

And I call it like this: (notice how arrays and hashes are passed)

```
bundle exec rake "foo:bar[name=abdo&fruits[]=apples&fruits[]=oranges&hash[foo]=bar&hash[cool]=notmuch]"
```

Output:

```
{"name"=>"abdo", "fruits"=>["apples", "oranges"], "hash"=>{"foo"=>"bar", "cool"=>"notmuch"}}
```

Comment: the [envied](https://github.com/eval/envied) gem does something [similar](https://github.com/eval/envied#types): `:hash (e.g. 'a=1&b=2' becomes {'a' => '1', 'b' => '2'})`

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your :p variable in task as a hash maybe? :p => {}

task :post_hit, [:host, :title, :description, :model, :num_assignments, :reward, :lifetime, :qualifications, :p => {}, :opts